# Is the TCPIP link type compressed?

Tags: performance-tuning, mathlink-or-wstp, remote-access

Since I'm already piping a *MathLink* connection in a ssh tunnel (connect back is a pain!), I wonder if it makes sense to compress the data in the stream (`ssh -C`). As with any optimization matter, one should measure, but unfortunately it seems there's no way to get statistics out of `ssh` on the connection so I cannot just test and measure the gain or loss. My question is then, is it known whether this *MathLink* type is already compressed?

Comment: My naive guess is that it is not.  The guess is based on the fact that large enough GraphicsBox expressions get compressed explicitly before being sent to the kernel.

Comment: What's the source of this example?

Comment: It isn't compressed. Whether you would see any improvement using your own compression is hard to guess.

Comment: I have to correct myself.  They're compressed after being sent, not before.

Comment: @ToddGayley I see you're a programmer at Wolfram, please explain me why they choose this painful double (!) connect back mechanism. With a single instance of `ssh` (that you have to issue anyway to launch the process) you already have a bidirectional pipe, why not use that?

Comment: There are two separate TCP connections in each link because one is used for data and the other is for MathLink messages (like MLTerminateMessage, MLAbortMessage, etc.) These messages have to be delivered even if the data channel is stalled.

Comment: As for ssh, remember that ssh has no role whatsoever in the TCP link between the two sides. It is only a method to remotely launch the kernel from another computer.